# Boolean in swagger sent as string instead of boolean in NestJS

Tags: typescript, swagger, postman, nestjs

I'm not understanding why Swagger is sending my boolean value as a string and not as a boolean.

I have set the value of the field as a boolean in the Dto.

It's working with Postman sending a boolean but not with Swagger which is sending as a string...

Here is my controller using the `CreateIssueDto`

```js
/**
   * Create an issue
   * @param image
   * @param issue
   */
  @ApiBearerAuth()
  @ApiOperation({ description: 'Create an issue' })
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('image'))
  @ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
  @Roles(Role.HeadOfPole, Role.Corrector, Role.Editor)
  @Post('create')
  createIssue(@UploadedFile() image, @Body() issue: CreateIssueDto) {
    image ? (issue.image = image.path) : null;
    return this.issuesService.createIssue(issue);
  }
```

Here is my `CreateIssueDto` with Swagger decorators

```js
import { ApiProperty, ApiPropertyOptional } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateIssueDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  userId: number;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  description: string;

  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  isCritical: boolean;

  @ApiPropertyOptional({ type: 'string', format: 'binary' })
  image: string;
}
```

I added two logs to print the difference in the controller

```js
console.log(issue);
console.log(issue.isCritical, typeof issue.isCritical);
```

So here is the object and the type of `isCritial` using Swagger

```sh
[Object: null prototype] {
  userId: '1',
  description: 'There is a problem',
  isCritical: 'true'
}
true string
```

And here is the object and the type of `isCritial` using Postman

```sh
{ userId: 1, description: 'There is a problem', isCritical: true }
true boolean
```

Answer (score 1):

Swagger is sending the boolean as a string. You must use a custom value `Transformation` that converts the value to a boolean when it is a string.

`to-boolean.ts`:

```
import { Transform, TransformFnParams } from "class-transformer";

export function ToBoolean(): (target: any, key: string) => void {
    return Transform((params: TransformFnParams) => {
        const { value } = params;
        if (typeof value === 'boolean') {
            return value;
        }
        if (value?.toString()?.toLowerCase() === 'false') {
            return false;
        }
        if (value?.toString()?.toLowerCase() === 'true') {
            return true;
        }
        return undefined;
    });
}
```

Then update your DTO to use `@ToBoolean()` as a decorator.

`my-dto.ts`

```
import { ApiProperty } from "@nestjs/swagger";
import { ToBoolean } from "./to-boolean";

export class MyDto {
    @ApiProperty({ required: false, default: false })
    @ToBoolean()
        isCritical?: boolean;
}
```

And make sure your Nest Application includes a `ValidationPipe` with the `transform` option enabled. For example:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
    transform: true
}));
```

More details on validation pipes in the NestJS documentation: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#using-the-built-in-validationpipe

Answer (score 0):

Use **Transform** function from **'class-transformer'** to fix it, there are two approaches:

First one, transform the value directly in the dto file:

```
@Transform(value => {
  return value === 'true' || value === true || value === 1 || value === '1'
})
isCritical: boolean;
```

The second approaches, which highly recommended, export a **ToBoolean** function under the **decorators** repository, and use it everywhere:

```
 export function ToBoolean(): (target: any, key: string) => void {
    return Transform((value: any) => value === 'true' || value === true || value === 1 || value === '1');
}
```

CreateIssueDto file:

```
export class CreateIssueDto {
  ///
  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  @ToBoolean()
  isCritical: boolean;
  ///
```

note: If `transform: true` is not set as an option of the `ValidationPipe` then the `@Transform()` you are using will only be used in memory for the `class-validator` check and not persist as the value passed to your route handler. Setting `transform: true` means that Nest will pass back the `plainToInstance` value for what was already sent in.

Comment: I had to destruct the "value" on transform on the function wrapper
"export function ToBoolean(): (target: any, key: string) => void {
  return Transform(({ value, ...props }: any) => {
    return (
      value === 'true' || value === true || value === 1 || value === '1'
    );
  });
}"

Comment: It's important to note that the unless `{transform:true}` is set on the ValidationPipe, the transform will not actually affect the object that is passed back to the controller - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72264012/228369

Answer (score 0):

maybe because in file main.ts of your project you have enableImplicitConversion in true, you need change that variable to false and with this change variables sent by postman doesn't change the type.

This change works for me, I hope it will useful for you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZaZd.png)