# @Transform() Boolean Cast Doesn't Work on DTO

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I'm using nestJS and class-transformer inside a DTO.

Here's a simple example of what I did and my issue:

```
    export class SomeDTO{
        @Transform(({ value }) => value === "true" || value === true || value === 1)
        @IsBoolean()
        doDelete : boolean;
    }
```

I tried even `@Transform(({ value }) => { return  value === "true" || value === true || value === 1})`

Now, in my controller:

```
@Post("something")
someOperation(@Body()  data : SomeDTO){
    console.log(data); 
}
```

Logging the data, the intended boolean `doDelete` is still a string and wasn't transformed to its native boolean type.

Did tried proviiding any data like this:
`@Transform(({ value }) => { return false})`

But in the controller, the data is still the same if we set the original DTO doDelete to true. It's not converting to false as we implied via `@Transform()`.

Did I do something wrong? Appreciated the help and shedding some light.

I've tried these related references but nothing seems to work.

- [Boolean in swagger sent as string instead of boolean in NestJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66093415/boolean-in-swagger-sent-as-string-instead-of-boolean-in-nestjs)
- https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/766#issuecomment-470261677

Comment: Do you have the `transform: true` option set in your `ValidationPipe`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Correct. I didn't put `transform : true` on the validation pipe. Would you mind posting this in the answer section so that I could select this as the solution? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `transform: true` is not set as an option of the `ValidationPipe` then the `@Transform()` you are using will only be used in memory for the `class-validator` check and not persist as the value passed to your route handler. Setting `transform: true` means that Nest will pass back the `plainToInstance` value for what was already sent in.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting observation. I have added `ValidationPipe` with necessary parameters, but it didn't work.
Spent a lot of time googling for what i did wrong, but no success.

Eventually everything worked after a restarted my application. For some reason watcher didn't loaded configuration of the pipe.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32746273)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).